# <audio> play/pause button change

Tags: javascript, audio

how could I make this happen? For example...

Once I have clicked 'play the audio' the text changes to 'pause the audio'. Once the sound has finished, change back to original text. At the moment it is displaying both text side by side.

Below is what im using:

```
<audio id="demo" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id, 'full' ); ?>"></audio>
<div>
  <a onclick="document.getElementById('demo').play()">Play the Audio</a>
  <a onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()">Pause the Audio</a>
</div>
```

If anyone could help that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Use Audio API events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the markup to

```
<div>
  <a id="play" onclick="togglePlay('play')">Play the Audio</a>
  <a id="pause" onclick="togglePlay('pause')" style="display:none">Pause the Audio</a>
</div>
```

And do something like :

```
function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
   if (obj.addEventListener) {
     obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
   } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
     obj.attachEvent("on" + type, fn);
   }
}

addEvent(document.getElementById('demo'), 'ended', function() {
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('pause').style.display = 'none';
});

function togglePlay(state) {
    var audio = document.getElementById('demo'),
        play  = document.getElementById('play'),
        pause = document.getElementById('pause');

    if (state == 'play') {
        audio.play();
        play.style.display = 'none';
        pause.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        audio.pause();
        play.style.display = 'block';
        pause.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: ah that worked thanks, but it doesn't reset once audio has finished. Is there anyway of doing that?